# Laravel Controler-Route / action with GET-Parameters

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, get, controller

I would like to append some GET parameters likes ?date=1234567&checked=1 to my controller route. I thought about something like this in my *blade.php file:

```
<a href="{{ URL::action('ReportController@getReport', array('id'=> $message->EnergyMeterID, 'date' =>$message->created_at)) }}"> {{ $message->object }}</a>
```

However this results in /608b1308-d29a-43e3-a396-0d3a72d640d7/1234567.

It works with the following approach:

```
... {{ URL::action('ReportController@getReport', $message->EnergyMeterID) }}?date={{ $message->CreateDate }}"> ...
```

like this:

```
http://url-to-domain/report/608b1308-d29a-43e3-a396-0d3a72d640d7?date=123456
```

But, is there a built-in function?

Comment: [**http_build_query**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: How to use this with laravel? {{ URL::action('ReportController@getMeter', http_build_query(array($message->EnergyMeterID, 'date'=>$message->CreateDate))) }} like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @itachi mentioned in the comments. There's the [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) php function. It converts an array into a query string.

Here's how you use it:

```
{{ URL::action('ReportController@getReport') }}?{{ http_build_query(array('id'=> $message->EnergyMeterID, 'date' =>$message->created_at)) }}
```

#### Update

If you have route params *and* query params just generate your root link like you would

```
{{ URL::action('ReportController@getReport', $message->EnergyMeterID) }}?{{ http_build_query(array('date' =>$message->created_at)) }}
```

Comment: change the `&` to `?`

Comment: Thanks, but I need the first argument as a normal route. I've added an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $data = ['param1' => 'value1', 'param2',=>'value2']; // the parameters you want to send.
```

in view:

```
{{ URL::action('ReportController@getMeter', $message->EnergyMeterID) }} ? {{http_build_query($data)}}
```